# Refresh a partial view from itself

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

So i got a real and ,I'm sure, pretty dumb problem.

So I got my main view in wich one I call a partial view.

Here is the code to call the partial view from the controller.

```
        public ActionResult DetailsBref(int id, string n, string m)
    {
        //id = id de l'initiative, n = user, m = mobile
        ViewBag.initiative = id;
        ViewBag.user = int.Parse(n);

        var retourContenu = new List<Contenu>();
        var listUser = new List<Utilisateur>();

        WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        //Client http pour se connecter à la web api
        HttpClient MyClient = new HttpClient(handler);

        //secure
        CS_Cryptage crypt = new CS_Cryptage();
        string authInfo = crypt.Crypter("StageChwapi", 3);
        //string authInfo = "StageChwapi";
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
        MyClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authInfo);

        MyClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62624/");
        MyClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        MyClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); //demande du Json
        /*Récupération des contenus*/
        HttpResponseMessage responseContent = MyClient.GetAsync("api/ApiStage/GetContenu/" + id).Result; //contact de la méthode GetProfil
        if (responseContent.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            retourContenu.AddRange(responseContent.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Contenu>>().Result); //permet le mappage depuis le Json
        }
        /*Récupération des utilisateurs*/
        HttpResponseMessage responseUtilisateur;
        foreach (var tmp in retourContenu)
        {
            responseUtilisateur = MyClient.GetAsync("api/ApiStage/GetUtilisateur/" + tmp.FkIdutilisateur).Result;
            if (responseContent.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //var user = 
                listUser.Add(responseUtilisateur.Content.ReadAsAsync<Utilisateur>().Result); //permet le mappage depuis le Json
                //tmp.NomPrenom = user.Nom + " " + user.Prenom;
            }
        }

        ViewBag.Contenu = retourContenu;
        ViewBag.Utilisateurs = listUser;
        ViewBag.Mobile = m;
        return PartialView(@"~\Views\Shared\_DetailsBref.cshtml", retourContenu);
    }
```

And the JScode to display it in the main view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getView(id, n) {
        var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("DetailsBref", "Alfred", new { id = "-id", n = "-n" }))";
        url = url.replace("-id", id);
        url = url.replace("-n", n);
        $('#mainContent').load(url);
    }
</script>
```

Atm the parameters for the partial view are hardcoded. The thing is that the partial view is a discussion thread and I can display it by clicking on a button in the main view.
But in the partial view, I want to add the possibility to edit a post and when it's done, reload only the partial view. At the moment, the user can edit his text and the modification is saved in the DB and displayed when you reload the whole project but it doesn't reload.

Here is the SaveUpdate method from the controller which is called when the user is done.

```
        [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult SaveUpdate(string editor1, int idcontenu, int user)
    {
        string save = "";
        if (editor1 != null)
            save = TraitementCommentaire(editor1);
        var c = new Contenu();
        c.Idcontenu = idcontenu;
        c.FkIdutilisateur = user;
        c.Donnee = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(editor1);
        c.Datemodif = System.DateTime.Now;

        WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        //Client http pour se connecter à la web api
        HttpClient MyClient = new HttpClient(handler);

        //secure
        CS_Cryptage crypt = new CS_Cryptage();
        string authInfo = crypt.Crypter("StageChwapi", 3);
        //string authInfo = "StageChwapi";
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
        MyClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authInfo);

        MyClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62624/");
        MyClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        MyClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); //demande du Json
        HttpResponseMessage response = MyClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ApiStage/PostUpdateContenu", c).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //textHtml.Text = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result; //permet le mappage depuis le Json
        }

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

And the call in the partial view is makde like that

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getView(id, n) {
        var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("DetailsBref", "Alfred", new { id = "-id", n = "-n" }))";
        url = url.replace("-id", id);
        url = url.replace("-n", n);
        $('#mainContent').load(url);
    }
</script>
```

And I call it in JQuery like that :

```
 getView(40375,5489);
```

And finally, here is the point. I get that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqbnT.png

Thx for taking time for me !

Have a good day !

Comment: Are you calling your own API methods from inside your actions?

Comment: The way you're using PartialViews is very strange to me.  You appear to be making another HTTP call to pull the raw HTML into your page, whereas a partial view should be already embedded in the page from the first request.

Comment: @BradChristie No they are on a server but I have to hide the link because I'm in an internship.

Comment: @m.edmondson  I'm pretty new to asp.Net so I do my best with what I know . If you have some way to improve my code I'm ready to listen ! :D

Comment: @Erunayc: Have a look at `RestSharp` and look at turning that into a service/repository that you can reference one-off (like `contenuService.Add(c)` or `contenuService.Get(id)`.

Comment: @BradChristie I'll take a look at that thx for that but it doesn't resolve my reloading problem ^^'